# Cosa significa "tenerne conto" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il giorno della civetta*, di Leonardo Sciascia, ho letto:

> La natura imita l'arte: ammazzato sulle scene liriche dalla musica di Mascagni e dal coltello di compare Alfio, Turiddu Macca cominciò a popolare le mappe turistiche della Sicilia e i tavoli d'autopsia. Ma qualche volta, di coltello o di lupara (non più di musica, per fortuna), la peggio toccava ai compari Alfio: e il capitano Bellodi, in quel momento, non sapeva **tenerne conto**; e questa distrazione avrebbe pagato con una piccola censura.

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "tenerne conto" in questo brano. Ho cercato alla voce "conto" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato o non ho saputo trovare nulla che abbia senso in questo contesto. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Da Treccani, nella definizione di [conto](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/conto2/):

> ***tenere conto*** (seguito da un complemento di specificazione o da una
>   prop. introdotta dall’espressione del fatto che o semplicem. da che),
>   fare la debita valutazione di una circostanza: bisogna tener conto
>   delle sue reazioni; tieni conto (del fatto) che è già molto tardi;

I riferimenti sono relativi alla [Cavalleria rusticana](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalleria_rusticana_(opera)), che è un'opera in un unico atto di Pietro Mascagni, su libretto di Giovanni Targioni-Tozzetti e Guido Menasci, tratto dalla [novella omonima](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalleria_rusticana_(novella)) di Giovanni Verga.

Nella novella è compare Turiddu che cade sotto i colpi del pugnale di Alfio, ma Sciascia lascia intendere che ogni tanto nella realtà succede il contrario.

Nel passaggio da te citato **tenerne conto** significa che il protagonista non sapeva considerare i particolari, magari evidenti, con la giusta attenzione, mancanza per cui sarebbe stato rimproverato in seguito.